# HP 2000-2d04TU Notebook (Ubuntu 12.04) wireless internet disabled

Tags: wireless

I have a HP 2000-2d04TU Notebook pc.In my system I have loaded ubuntu 12.04 but  wifi is disabled in my system.

Comment: paste the output of "rfkill list all " here

Answer (score 0):

- Run the below command to check if your wifi is hardblocked or softblocked,

  ```
  sudo rfkill list
  ```
- If your wifi is softblocked then try to unblock it by running the below command,

  ```
  sudo rfkill unblock wlan
  ```
- If it is hardblocked,then try to find the hardware switch to enable wifi.