# wi-fi works during the live trial, not after install

Tags: wireless, internet

I was running Windows 8 64 bit on an Acer travelmate B113 with 2GB of RAM.
I then installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS using a USB drive. Everything was working fine and I was able to access the internet via wi-fi during the trial.

Once I accessed the installed version of ubuntu, I could still connect to my router, but accessing the internet didn't work anymore. Every page I try to load in Firefox immediatly says the page isn't available. I'm now on the Windows 8 part of the computer, and everything seems to work fine.

How to find a solution?

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/385826/hp-2000-2d04tu-notebook-ubuntu-12-04-wireless-internet-disabled/385827#385827

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu may have pulled in proprietary drivers for your card during installation. By chance, these drivers may actually work worse than the open-source ones Ubuntu has built-in. Go to System Settings -> Hardware Drivers and remove any wireless ones, then try again.